# How to define a Rails route on resource member and have it appear at the end of the route name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a route in my Rails application that looks like this:

```
resources :products
  get :specs, on: :member
end
```

This results in the route helper: `specs_product_path` instead of `product_specs_path`. How can I define the route so that the "specs action" is added to the end of the helper method instead of the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You can always declare a sub-resource which follows this convention:

```
 resources :products do
  resources :specs, only: [ :index ]
 end
```

This will require creating another controller, though, with an `index` action.

You should also be able to override the name with the `as:` option:

```
resources :products do
  get :specs, on: :member, as: :product_specs
end
```

Generally it's a good idea to adhere to convention as every exception can lead to confusion or conflict down the road.

Comment: specifying `as: :product_specs` results in `product_specs_product_path`

Comment: You may need to create a custom route outside of that namespace. The `as:` approach is less desirable.